# Session array into javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, session

I have a problem to get in a session array from php into a javascript

I´m setting the sessions array here, the `print_r` is only for checking so it´s correct

```
  while($row2[]=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    $_SESSION['row2'] = $row2; 
  print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][0]);
  print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][1]);
  print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][2]);
```

and in my javascript i use this, alert is only for checking

```
 var row2 =<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['row2']) ?>;
 alert (row2[0][0]);
 alert (row2[0][1]);
 alert (row2[0][2]);
```

`row2[0][0]` and `row2[0][1]`, works fine, I get the numbers from the array
but `row2[0][2]` give me the value null, it should be some text in this field, it´s works fine with `print_r($_SESSION['row2'][0][2]);` in the php-code.

Comment: Can you `view source` in your browser and see what does `var row2 = ...` become? (actually, see the JSON on the javascript side)

Comment: {"0":"27","chapterNumber":"27","1":"0","number":"0","2":null,"nameOfTask":null}

Comment: Well, from this output it's clear as rain, index `2` is in fact null.  If echoing $row2[ 0 ][ 2 ] prints a value, then the problem is either when inserting the value & then extracting it from the `$_SESSION` collection or with `json_encode()`, what is the value which should appear for $row[ 0 ][ 2 ]?

Comment: the value for $row[0][2] is "Rätt eller fel!"
And I have discovered why it´s beeing null, it´s when I use swedish charactar å,ä,ö. When not using them it´s work!!!

Comment: Is it a new question how to solve this by using swedish charactar or should i update this question, I´m new here. And I need to use the swedish charactar!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use firebug console or chrome console. After that dump the entire `row2` into the console and preview the data.

```
// JavaScript
var row2 =<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['row2']) ?>;
console.debug(row2);
```

Also, keep in mind that all PHP associative arrays will become JSON object and should be accessed with `.`

Comment: Thanx it helped me a lot, I found the problem, it´s when I use swedish charactar å,ä,ö. When not using them it´s work!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the Array, but keep in mind the result is a string, so you have to enclose it with single quotes and then parse it into an object:

```
var row2 = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['row2']) ?>';
row2 = JSON.parse(row2);
```

Comment: gives the same result as before

Answer (score 0):

As Alex stated, if you have an associative array into PHP, the json_encode output won't be the same.

Is it possible that it's the problem? As you seem not to use the associative keys, you may avoid to use mysql_fetch_array and could try mysql_fetch_row instead.

(Nb: your code is weird)

Comment: I have just finished a course in PHP and this is my first "work", I`ve never used JSON before I saw it on an other question here, I have to study that more. I don´t know if it´s the best way to get an PHP session array into javascript.